# ThrottleStop dosen't save SpeedShift SST Limits

Tags: intel-core-i7, dell-xps, cpu-speed, throttling, cpufreq

ThrottleStop dosen't save SpeedShift SST Limits in profile 1,2,3,4. I have to select a profile and everytime have to adjust speedshift limits manually opening TS. Is there a workarround for this ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

ThrottleStop does not have an option to save the Speed Shift Min and Max Limits to different values for each profile.

Adjusting the Turbo Ratio Limits is a better way to control CPU speed and can be set to different values for each profile.

Modern CPUs save power when the cores enter a low power C state. A core in C7 is disconnected from the internal clock and disconnected from the voltage rail so it is running at 0 MHz and 0 volts.

There is no practical benefit slowing a modern CPU down. Peak power consumption will decrease when fully loaded but total power consumption to complete a task is the same. A slow CPU is an inefficient CPU. A fast CPU gets tasks done quickly and this allows the cores to spend more time in C7. That is why Intel created Speed Shift Technology.

[Power Optimization – a Reality Check](https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/2009/EECS-2009-140.pdf)

Here is an example. Huge difference in CPU speed, no difference in CPU core temperature or reported power consumption.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs0K2.png)

Comment: But @unclewebb, i want to underclock below my base speed. I dont need 2.8Ghz(or 3.8Ghz) i am good with 1.9Ghz(for specific applications) rest is just useless power utilization and global warming. Please add this feature and save the planet !

I can help with additional code if its open source. Thanks !
Btw my CPU is i7-7700HQ ! Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But, the rate of heat generation or the power consumption decreases when cpu frequency is decreased, which is exactly what i wanted. I am not able to dissipate the heat generated by i7 CPU @ 3.8Ghz rather i can @ 1.9 Ghz. The picute shows no-load CPU power consuption difference, which is expected to be same but at full load, and indefinate task(i wont allow the cpu to go into sleep state), the cpu power consumption increases in the two scenarios, greated in the case which has higher cpufreq.

Comment: I am Still waiting on this... :/

Comment: [link](https://i.imgur.com/NykJfRT.png)

Comment: The TPL window even 9.2.9 does not have those profiles shows above uncle, which version are you using ?

Comment: UNCLE PLEASEEEEE !!! Still Waiting :(